# CakePHP Call To A Member Function query() On Null

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.3

So I am trying to make an ajax call with an entity Id and query a data of that. As far as I know, if an url is such *abc.com/xyz/123* then it will hit xyz controller with 123 as parameter and I did that but it says, "An Internal Error Has Occurred". The error log states the headline of this thread.

The method is:

```
public function fetch($order_details_id)
{
    $sql = "SELECT 
                orders.id
                , ROUND(SUM(rolls.weight),2) as produced_qty
            FROM orders
            LEFT JOIN order_details ON order_details.buyer_order_id = orders.id
            LEFT JOIN knitting_plans ON knitting_plans.buyer_order_detail_id = order_details.id
            LEFT JOIN jobcards ON jobcards.knitting_plan_id = knitting_plans.id
            LEFT JOIN machines ON machines.id = jobcards.machine_id
            LEFT JOIN rolls ON rolls.jobcard_id = jobcards.id
            WHERE order_details.id = $order_details_id
            ORDER BY orders.id";

    $data = $this->BuyerOrder->query($sql);

    $this->set('data', $data);
}
```

What's wrong in this code?

URL: /buyerOrders/fetch/52629

Since my objective is to return the result in html/json format. Let me know if I could return in a better way.

Comment: It's trying to call `query` on null, the only `query` call here is on `$this->BuyerOrder`, so it's clear that this is what's null. It's probably `$this->BuyerOrders`, plural.

Answer (score 0):

**load model before query execution**
It's trying to call query on null, the only query call here is on $this->BuyerOrder, so it's clear that it ***unable to find BuyerOrder***.
So load model

```
$this->loadModel('BuyerOrder');
```